# Directive is not receiving array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm building a directive that gets 2 arrays from controller and shows then in two lists. But i don't know why, when i use

```
window.alert(scope.firstList);
window.alert(scope.secondList);
```

i get undefined from the firstList. The second list is null, that's okay, it's supposed to be true, but i don't know why i'm getting undefined on the first.
The same list, when i show it on the page, it's normal:
[image]

code: http://jsfiddle.net/r88tmobj/

Someone could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please add your output as text, not an image

Comment: That's just to show that i'm able to show the array on the screen and i'm getting it null at my directive

Comment: What is the value of "listaPessoaFuncionarioTreinado" in the scope of the parent controller where the "gumga-lists" element is used?

Comment: The array in the picture

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't reproduce the problem.  I included references to AngularJS and RequireJS, but it still threw some [nasty console errors](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch).